# Fix html inside a for loop

Tags: loop

I want to get the right link format for the second link, i tried many time to move the a open tag but no way the result is as the image below.

```
foreach( $terms as $term ) : 

    echo '<div class="one_half last">';

    $customposts = new WP_Query( "taxonomy=$taxonomy&term=$term->slug&posts_per_page=2" );

    echo '<ul>';
    if( $customposts->have_posts() ): while( $customposts->have_posts() ) : $customposts->the_post();
        echo '<li>';
        echo '<a href="'.the_permalink().'">'.the_title_attribute(); // The problem
        endwhile;  endif;
        echo '</a></li>';
    echo '</ul>';
    echo '</div>';
endforeach;
```

Thanks[image]

Comment: This appears to be a **PHP syntax** question, rather than a **WordPress**-specific question.

Comment: This is a Wordpress for loop

Comment: "*This is a Wordpress for loop.*" - Please [refer to the WPSE FAQ](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#questions). Just because a question takes place in the *context* of WordPress does not make the question inherently *in-scope for WPSE*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have the PHP syntax all messed up. Second, you misused some WordPress template tags - you already echo the entire link like so you need to return post permalink and title, but right now `the_permalink` and `the_title_attribute` functions echo the code.

Here's your code fixed:

```
foreach( $terms as $term ) :

    $customposts = new WP_Query( "taxonomy=$taxonomy&term=$term->slug&posts_per_page=2" );

    if( $customposts->have_posts() ):

        echo '<div class="one_half last">';
        echo '<ul>';

        while( $customposts->have_posts() ) : $customposts->the_post();
            echo '<li>';
            echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title(); // The problem
            echo '</a></li>';
        endwhile;

        echo '</ul>';
        echo '</div>';

    endif;

endforeach;
```